# Using Rails model method to fetch and return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, methods

### Problem

I currently have a method in my `models/listing.rb` which has a method like this:

```
 def self.lookup_info(val)
   # Fetch some data from the internet
   return{ price: value1, title: value2, isbn: val }
 end
```

When users plug in `val` into `views/listings/_form.html.erb` when creating a new listing, I want to call `lookup_info` and have it fill in the rest of the form if a result (not nil) is returned.

### Setup

controllers/listings_controller.rb

```
def new
  @listing = Listing.new
end
```

views/listings/new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form', listing: @listing %>
```

views/listings/_form.html.erb (I use div tags in actual code, but don't include below for simplicity)

```
<%= form_for(@listing, :html => {class: "form-horizontal" , role: "form"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :isbn, "ISBN" %>
    <%= f.text_field :isbn , class: "form-control" , id: "isbn_field", placeholder: "ISBN (10 or 13 digits - no dashes)", autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.label :price, "Price" %>
    <%= f.text_field :price , class: "form-control" , id: "price_field", placeholder: "Price" %>
    <%= f.label :title, "URL" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title , class: "form-control" , id: "title_field", placeholder: "Title" %>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
<% end %>
```

What javascript and rails do I need to make the _form.html.erb update when a user types in `users_isbn`, I call `lookup_info(users_isbn)` and then get an updated partial such that the values of the fields are set to the results.

**Example of response:**

```
<%= form_for(@listing, :html => {class: "form-horizontal" , role: "form"}) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :isbn, "ISBN" %>
        <%= f.text_field :isbn , class: "form-control" , id: "isbn_field", placeholder: "ISBN (10 or 13 digits - no dashes)", value: lookup_info(users_isbn)[:isbn] autofocus: true %>
        <%= f.label :price, "Price" %>
        <%= f.text_field :price , class: "form-control" , id: "price_field", placeholder: "Price", value: lookup_info(users_isbn)[:price] %>
... <!-- Same idea for title -->
<% end %>
```

### Current Start with Javascript

Here is what I have so far:

`_form.js.erb` (not sure if this would be the right name for the js file)

```
var isbnField = document.getElementById('#isbn_field').value;
if (isbnField.length == (10 || 13)){
  var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
        url: "listings/lookup",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {isbn: $('#isbn_field').val()}
      });
      ajaxResponse.success(function(){
        alert("Success"); # I would actually want to <%= j render #name of form partial with values %>
      });
      ajaxResponse.error(function(){
         alert("Could not find that ISBN");
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest doing it as follows.

`listings_controller.rb`

```
# your new action

# your search action
def search
  @foo = lookup_info(val) 
  # You might have to change this line to something like
  # self.lookup_info(val) since I can't see the exact application of
  # your lookup_info method. But the idea is you would want to put
  # the return values into your @foo.
  if @foo
    respond_to { |format| format.js { render listings/success }
  else
    respond_to { |format| format.js {render listings/failure }
  end
end
```

Explanation for controller action:
Your form would be submitting to the controller action `search`. If `@foo` is valid, meaning if the search is successful, it will render the successful partial view which we will be creating, else we will be rendering a view to handle failed form submissions (assuming you need it).

`routes.rb`

```
get "my-search-url", to: "listings#search", as: "my_search_url"
# you can set your own route names
# i assume your form is a get instead of post action
```

Now for your form, change it to `form_with`

```
<%= form_with(url: my_search_url_path) do |f| %>
```

If you are using Rails 4 instead of Rails 5, you can't use `form_with`, instead you'd have to use `remote: true` which would handle the ajax request for you.

Lastly, in your views, you need these 2 components, the `js.erb` and the partial

`success.js.erb`

```
$("#holder-for-search").html("<%= j render partial: 'listings/success' %>");
$("#bigger-holder-for-search").fadeIn("1000");

# note that the file name has to be the same as what your respond_to is rendering in your search action
# also remember to create a failure.js.erb too to handle the failed search
```

`_success.html.erb`

```
# render what you want to show if search is successful
```

And in your `new.html.erb` or wherever the form is displayed, simply have your relevant `div` with the correct ID tags (such as #holder-for-search)

```
<div id="bigger-holder-for-search" style="display:none;">
  <div id="holder-for-search">
  </div>
</div>

// and you can consider fading everything else out to fade in your search response
```

In summary, to reproduce an AJAX response, you need 4 components:

1) In your controller action, you need `respond_to { |format| format.js }`

2) You need to have a corresponding `js.erb` in your view (must be named exactly either like the controller action, or the respond_to response)

3) The partial to be rendered by your `js.erb`

4) A `remote: true` action. If its a link, you include it in the link, if its a form, you include it in your form. In rails 5, `form_with` implies `remote: true` hence you don't need to explicitly type that out.